# Object is possibly 'null'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

не  могу решить проблему:  content.current возможно равен значению "null"

````
import "./Accordion.css"
import Chevron from "./Chevron"

type PropsType = {
  title: string
  content: string
  
}

export const Accordion: React.FC<PropsType> = (props) => {
  const [setActive, setActiveState] = useState("")
  const [setHeight, setHeightState] = useState("0px")
  const [setRotate, setRotateState] = useState("accordion__icon")

  const content = useRef(null)

  function toggleAccordion() {
    setActiveState(setActive === "" ? "active" : "")
    setRotateState(
      setActive === "active" ? "accordion__icon" : "accordion__icon rotate"
    )
    setHeightState(
      setActive === "active" ? " 0px" : `${content.current.scrollHeight}px`
    )
  }

  return (
    <div className="accordion__section">
      <button className={`accordion ${setActive}`} onClick={toggleAccordion}>
        <p className="accordion__title">{props.title}</p>
        <Chevron width={10} fill={"#777"} className={`${setRotate}`} />
      </button>
      <div
        ref={content}
        style={{ maxHeight: `${setHeight}` }}
        className="accordion__content"
      >
        <div
          className="accordion__text"
          dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: props.content }}
        ></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Accordion ```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBIj8.png
````

Comment: что должно происходить в случае, если `content.current` - null???

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы избавиться от этой ошибки ,нужно просто добавить проверку что-то типо
if (content.current !== null) { код, который использует этот content.current} туда, где ты используешь content.current